# How to set table background transparent in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, transparent

I am new to iphone development .I have displayed a list of contents in a grouped table view.How can set the table background transparent such as i should  see the text displayed on the gray-color(default color) background and not on the white color.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: It would appear that the above is required even if the background is set to "Clear Color" and the cell is marked as not "Opaque" in the storyboard. (XCode 5)

Answer (score 3):

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Marco

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = nil;
table.backgroundView = nil;
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 seems this is not enough. I have to set both,

```
menuTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
if ([menuTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundView:)]) { // only after 3.2
    [menuTable setBackgroundView:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

Works on iOS 9.

Answer (score -3):

UITableView inherits a 'alpha' property from UIView so try changing that :)

Comment: I am using grouped tables how can i change the alpha value for the first table alone

Comment: So you want the first group in one table to be transparent or do you actually have several tables?

Comment: I want the first group in one table to be transparent

Comment: Not sure then apart from making the cells themselves transparent or writing your own UITableView

Comment: op is using grouped tables